# Horde Web-Mail classified as UBE

Tags: spam, amavis, horde, razor

I run a postfix, amavis-new, dovecot setup for mail service on my LAN, which works nicely for a long time. I recently added a horde imp server in my DMZ - actually behind IPv4 NAT using port forwarding. Which also works quite nice according to my early tests.

However, if I write e-mails using imp, these are classified as UBE dropping me a mail note: "Considered UNSOLICITED BULK EMAIL, apparently from you"

Analyzing the header it seems that imp acts as an MTA. I see two "Received:" headers: Smartphone->Horde-Imp, Horde-Imp->Postfix. I had expected Imp to act as MUA instead, but ...

The mail.log shows that amavis marks the mail as SPAM. But there's no log entry as to why it deems it such. Amavis is configured to use Razor and Pyzor. I did another test where the client had a different IP and the mail was actually delivered.

Comment: I think you need to look at/add details of the specific reasons for the messages being tagged as UBE. If this is happening locally that should be in your logs or failing that in the headers/body of the rejection.

Comment: Seems like I shouldn't work on such thinks while having a flu. Yes, the logs clearly say that amavis tagged it SPAM for 10.102 hits.
Strange, I sent a test-mail and it worked, but at that time my smart-phone had a different IP, also outside my LAN area. Have I just been unlicky to have gotten a black-listed IP?

Comment: Do you use a dialup connection, so got a dynamic IP?

Comment: The client is dynamic. The server is static.